# Microsoft Graph API: Share point site search query for contentclass = ''STS_List_Tasks"

Tags: c#, sharepoint, office365, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

Hi the following share point search query `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites?search=contoso` is working.  I want to list all sites which has "**contentclass**" value equal to "**STS_List_Task**". How can it be achieved using Graph api.

Comment: Content class isn't provided via the Microsoft Graph sites API currently. We're investigating how we can make useful information available via the API. Can you elaborate more on what you're looking to accomplish here?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Currently i am using Share point rest api to get all sites with  "contentclass" value equal to "STS_List_Task". My need is to get current user tasks in those sites. But i want to use Graph API with Azure Active Directory v2.0 Authentication. How can i achieve this using GRAPH API.